# How can I easily find the release date of a laptop by model number?

Tags: laptop

I need to find the release date of a large number of laptop computers. What is a reliable online source?

Comment: Can we get a little more information on this such as manufacturers? Some provide more information than others.

Comment: http://www.fcc.gov/complaints

Comment: http://search2.fcc.gov/search/index.htm

Comment: Basically it concerns all manufacturers active on the European market and all their internet enabled devices.